# Create a dropdownlist with countries name

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, country

I want to create a dropdownlist that will contain the names of countries.

I have tried this:

```
ViewBag.country =
                from p in
                    CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures)
                               .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = p.EnglishName,
                        Value = p.DisplayName
                    };
```

But instead of giving me the names of countries, it gives me the languages and then the country in which it is spoken...

Here's the view, simple as "hello":

```
Country: @Html.DropDownList("country")
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

***Note*** I cannot use a dropdownlistfor because the country dropdownlist in my view is not bound with my model. I just want to populate a dropdownlist with the name of countries as string that I will reuse after.

Comment: Shouldnt `Text = p.EnglishName` be `Text = p.DisplayName` or just `p.Name`?

Comment: I have tried, but this gives out the exact same result :/

Comment: Eh? [According to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname.aspx) that should work.

Comment: According to that link, CultureInfo doesn't have a list of countries, which is what Herve S is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
@Html.DropDownList("country")
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country)
```

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that I cannot bind the country to my model because I have a list of my model in my view.

Comment: @HerveS How about @Html.DropDownListFor("country", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.country) then?

Comment: That's worth a try, I'll get you back on this.

Comment: No can do, since "country" is not a part or item of my model. I cannot use a strongly-type drowndownlist since I am not using the value in part of my model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable Country= ViewBag.country;
var country = (from L in Country.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           Value = L["DisplayName"],
                           Text = L["EnglishName"]
                       });    

@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", new SelectList(country, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { style = "width:150px" })
```

Answer (score 0):

The country name can be retrieved from the RegionInfo actually. Try this:

```
var countries = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID)).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.EnglishName);
ViewBag.country = new SelectList(countries, "Name", "EnglishName");
```